# What single word does a programmer call the control and command keys?

Tags: keyboard, cross-platform, keyboard-shortcuts, terminology, nomenclature

The **control** and **command** keys are basically analogs when it comes to computer applications, when I'm talking about them in a cross-platform application, what should they be called? Is there a term like " the _______ key"?

Comment: Hi Mark, with nearly [200 closed terminology questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=4&tab=relevance&q=%5bterminology%5d%20closed%3atrue) I'm not sure if flagging for a refund of the bounty would not be a better idea.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that statement, that the question will probably be closed as not-constructive? Maybe, but I don't really care about the bounty, and I have found the current answers helpful so I'm happy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alt / Shift / Control / Command - they're all modifier keys. Ctrl/Command are analogs in the sense that they're used for "command"-type shortcuts, i.e. performing some action. Maybe a C-modifier key or action-modifier key would be the right names.

Comment: Sat on it a few days, really like this answer though, "c-modifier" or something of the likes. Short and sweet answer that I think hits on all that needs to be said @philipxy 's answer was pretty interesting too but didn't really give me a satisfying answer at the end. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

"Modifier key" is the term  at least used many online dictionaries and documentation. (Including Apple and IBM.) (As used but not quite advocated in [ALGOholic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35333533/3404097).)

FYI there is an old term that has been used: "bucky (bit) keys". From [The Hacker's Dictionary](http://jargon-file.org/archive/jargon-1.5.0.dos.txt):

> BUCKY BITS noun.

> Control characters are so useful that sometimes special keyboards
>   are built that have even more shift keys. One of the first of these was
>   used at Stanford. It had the usual shift and control keys, and a third
>   key called "meta", as well as lots of unusual characters such as Greek
>   letter. So, one can type such characters as control-F, meta-N, and
>   control-meta-B.
>
> Now, when you type a character on a Stanford keyboard, the
>   following information is sent to the computer: a code indicating the
>   basic character, plus one BIT for each shifting key to indicate whether
>   that shifting key was pressed along with the basic character key.
>   Programs usually treat the regular shift key as part of the basic
>   character, indicating whether you want lower case or upper case (or
>   whether you want "3" or "#", and so on). The other bits (control and
>   meta) are called the bucky bits.

(Observe that the source itself refers to "shift keys" and "shifting keys".

See also [the jargon file glossary](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/bucky-bits.html):

> bucky bits: /buh'kee bits/, n.
>
> 1. [obs.] The bits produced by the CONTROL and META shift keys on a SAIL keyboard [...] (see space-cadet keyboard).
> 2. By extension, bits associated with ‘extra’ shift keys on any keyboard, e.g., the ALT on an IBM PC or command and option keys on a Macintosh.

Observe that the source itself refers to the bucky keys as "‘extra’ shift keys".

(I observe that "Bucky bits" & "space cadet keyboard" are referenced in the Wikipedia entry for ["modifier key"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key). Unfortunately, there isn't an etymology for "modifier key" itself.)